# How do I fix a HTTP Error 400 in my code?

Tags: c++, nodemcu

I am trying to make an rfid attendance system with NodeMCU8266.

I have gotten some code online and modified it with the help of a friend since I have zero experience with coding.

The code below scans an rfid card for data, and will then connect to a google sheet with google apps script. The code will show the web app url in the serial monitor that will send the data to google sheets automatically. However, I keep getting HTTPS GET: code 400 error and the data is not being sent to google sheets. But the web app url that shows up in serial monitor works when manually pasted into the address bar.

I have tried using the url fingerprint and the client.SetInsecure but it has not worked regardless of what i used. Any ideas what might be wrong? Your help is highly appreciated!

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <MFRC522.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.h>
//-----------------------------------------------------------
const String web_app_url = "ENTER WEB APP URL HERE";
//-----------------------------------------------------------
#define WIFI_SSID "SSID"
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "PASSWORD"
//-----------------------------------------------------------
int blocks[] = {4,5,6,8,9,10,12,13,14,18};
#define blocks_len  (sizeof(blocks) / sizeof(blocks[0]))
//-----------------------------------------------------------
//GPIO 0 --> D3
//GPIO 2 --> D4
//GPIO 4 --> D2
#define RST_PIN  D3
#define SS_PIN   D4
#define BUZZER   D0
#define GreenLed D1 //When WIFI is connected, LED ON.
#define YellowLed D8 // When CARD is scanned, LED ON.
#define RedLed D2 //When NODEMCU is not connected to WIFI, LED ON
//-----------------------------------------
MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
MFRC522::MIFARE_Key key;
MFRC522::StatusCode status;      
//-----------------------------------------
/* Be aware of Sector Trailer Blocks */
int blockNum = 2;  
/* Create another array to read data from Block */
/* Legthn of buffer should be 2 Bytes more than the size of Block (16 Bytes) */
byte bufferLen = 18;
byte readBlockData[18];
//-----------------------------------------
// Fingerprint for demo URL, expires on ‎Monday, ‎May ‎2, ‎2022 7:20:58 AM, needs to be updated well before this date
//const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = {0xb3 0x3f 0xf3 0xe4 0x5f 0x76 0x59 0x2e 0xf9 0xa2 0x0b 0xf7 0x99 0x5e 0x44 0x89 0x21 0x4d 0x2e 0x22};
//const uint8_t fingerprint[20] = {0xb3, 0x3f, 0xf3, 0xe4, 0x5f, 0x76, 0x59, 0x2e, 0xf9, 0xa2, 0x0b, 0xf7, 0x99, 0x5e, 0x44, 0x89, 0x21, 0x4d, 0x2e, 0x22};
//0x9a 0x71 0xde 0xe7 0x1a 0xb2 0x2c 0xab 0x4f 0x23 0x64 0x9a 0xbc 0xef 0x62 0x56 0x20 0x4e 0x43 c
//0x9a, 0x71, 0xde,0xe7, 0x1a, 0xb2, 0x25, 0xca, 0xb4, 0xf2, 0x36, 0x49, 0xab, 0xce, 0xf6, 0x25, 0x62, 0x04, 0xe4, 0x3c
//0xb3 0x3f 0xf3 0xe4 0x5f 0x76 0x59 0x2e 0xf9 0xa2 0x0b 0xf7 0x99 0x5e 0x44 0x89 0x21 0x4d 0x2e 0x22  -LATEST
//b33ff3e45f76592ef9a20bf7995e4489214d2e22
//-----------------------------------------





/****************************************************************************************************
 * setup() function
 ****************************************************************************************************/
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);        //Prevents reconnection issue (taking too long to connect)
  delay(1000);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);        //This line hides the viewing of ESP as wifi hotspot
  
  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);     //Connect to your WiFi router
  Serial.println("");

  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(WIFI_SSID);
  // Wait for connection
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("Connected");
  digitalWrite(GreenLed, HIGH);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP


  //--------------------------------------------------
  /* pin outputs */
  pinMode(BUZZER, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GreenLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(YellowLed, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RedLed, OUTPUT);
  //--------------------------------------------------
  /* Initialize SPI bus */
  SPI.begin();
  //--------------------------------------------------
    
}




/****************************************************************************************************
 * loop() function
 ****************************************************************************************************/
 void loop()
{
  if(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
    WiFi.disconnect();
    WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    Serial.print("Reconnecting to ");
    digitalWrite(RedLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(GreenLed,LOW);
    Serial.println(WIFI_SSID);
    WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("Connected");
    digitalWrite(RedLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(GreenLed, HIGH);
    Serial.print("IP address: ");
    Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP
  }
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Initialize MFRC522 Module */
  mfrc522.PCD_Init();
  /* Look for new cards */
  /* Reset the loop if no new card is present on RC522 Reader */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {return;}
  /* Select one of the cards */
  if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {return;}
  /* Read data from the same block */
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("Reading last data from RFID..."));  
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
   String fullURL = "", temp;
  for (byte i = 0; i < blocks_len; i++) {
    ReadDataFromBlock(blocks[i], readBlockData);
    if(i == 0){
      temp = String((char*)readBlockData);
      temp.trim();
      fullURL = "data" + String(i) + "=" + temp;
    }
    else{
      temp = String((char*)readBlockData);
      temp.trim();
      fullURL += "&data" + String(i) + "=" + temp;
    }
  }

  //Serial.println(fullURL);
  fullURL.trim();
  fullURL = web_app_url + "?" + fullURL;
  fullURL.trim();
  Serial.println(fullURL);
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
digitalWrite(YellowLed,HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, HIGH);
      delay(100);
      digitalWrite(YellowLed, LOW);
      digitalWrite(BUZZER, LOW);
      delay(100);
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
//MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
   if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //uncomment following line, if you want to use the SSL certificate
    //client->setFingerprint(fingerprint);
    //or uncomment following line, if you want to ignore the SSL certificate
    client->setInsecure();
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    HTTPClient https;
    Serial.print(F("[HTTPS] begin...\n"));
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    if (https.begin(*client, (String)fullURL)){
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      // HTTP
      Serial.print(F("[HTTPS] GET...\n"));
      // start connection and send HTTP header
      int httpCode = https.GET();
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      // httpCode will be negative on error
      if (httpCode > 0) {
        // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
        Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... code: %d\n", httpCode);
        // file found at server
      }
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      else 
      {Serial.printf("[HTTPS] GET... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());}
      //-----------------------------------------------------------------
      https.end();
      delay(1000);
    }
    //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
    else {
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS} Unable to connect\n");
    }
    //NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
  }
  //MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM
}




/****************************************************************************************************
 * ReadDataFromBlock() function
 ****************************************************************************************************/
void ReadDataFromBlock(int blockNum, byte readBlockData[]) 
{ 
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Prepare the ksy for authentication */
  /* All keys are set to FFFFFFFFFFFFh at chip delivery from the factory */
  for (byte i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    key.keyByte[i] = 0xFF;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Authenticating the desired data block for Read access using Key A */
  status = mfrc522.PCD_Authenticate(MFRC522::PICC_CMD_MF_AUTH_KEY_A, blockNum, &key, &(mfrc522.uid));
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------s
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK){
     Serial.print("Authentication failed for Read: ");
     Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
     return;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else {
    Serial.println("Authentication success");
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  /* Reading data from the Block */
  status = mfrc522.MIFARE_Read(blockNum, readBlockData, &bufferLen);
  if (status != MFRC522::STATUS_OK) {
    Serial.print("Reading failed: ");
    Serial.println(mfrc522.GetStatusCodeName(status));
    return;
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  else {
    readBlockData[16] = ' ';
    readBlockData[17] = ' ';
    Serial.println("Block was read successfully");  
  }
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

Comment: what's the url for your get request? Have you tried accessing the same URL from a web browser?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Based on the tutorial I followed, the url it gives is for google app script. Yes I have tried the URL from a web browser and it does send the data to my google sheets, but nodemcu cannot send the data on its own.

Comment: You need to strip everything from the sketch that is not strictly related to the problem to zero in on the issue.